# TYPO3 extension real_url returns 404 on all pages

Tags: typo3, typoscript, realurl

assume the following pagetree structure

- root
- client1

  - page 1
  - page 2
  - page 3
- client2

  - page 1
  - page 2
  - page 3

by default TYPO3 will display the page by id /index.php?id=[pid]

I'm trying to achieve the following effect

/client1/page1

so I came across the realurl extension which I did managed to make it work and I got the expected result in the url after setting

```
config.absRefPrefix = client1/
```

in my setup.ts field in my template

`realurl.basic.enableAutoConf = 1`

in the extension's configuration page

but now I'm getting a 404 on all pages when I access them like this `/client1/page1` and 
I only get the content without any css images and javascript when I access them over id 
because the `absRefPrefix` is now added to the resources

e.g. `/client1/fileadmin/assets/images/logo.jpg`

whats wrong with this picture?

**update 1:**

setting `absRefPrefix` = / did 'fix' everything everything however I'm not meeting the client requirement now

the client's name should be in the URL in this format 
`mysite.com/client1/page1`

right now I see `mysite.com/page1`

the client name is being skipped that was reason I added the client name in the `absRefPrefix`

Comment: it's because of your `config.absRefPrefix = client1/`. The real path of the picture is wwww.yoursite.com/fileadmin/assests/images/logo.jpg
Question : Why don't you put client1 and client2 under the root ? You'll not have to put client1 as absRefPrefix, and by default RealUrl will make you Urls like www.yoursite.com/client1/page1

Comment: the urls are created as expected and as you describe but they return 404

Comment: To solve the issue you need to move everything under root. Realurl works with hierarchies, so make it a hierarchy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like "user" i have to ask... why not place everything under root?

Then use:

```
config.absRefPrefix = /
config.simulateStaticDocuments = 0
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1
```

Answer to update1:
Check the pages Client1 and Client2, in page properties, general tab: Exclude from speaking URL should be left unchecked. RealUrl should by default create the structure you are looking for if the rootpage holds the domain and the client pages are really pages and not different websites.

Comment: they are under the root maybe its not clearly illustrated above but they are. and the extension seems to be working because the urls are now formatted as expected `mysite.com/client1/page-1` and so on.but when i visit them i get `404` not found maybe its something in the `.htaccess` file the url rewriting doesnt is done properly but i have followed the instructions of the manual very closely

Comment: 1. Is the rootpage marked as "Use as Root Page" in page properties behaviour tab? 
2. Is the .htaccess file placed in the root folder?
3. Does the .htaccess file have the correct file permissions?

Comment: Also, try setting basic.autoConfFormat to PHP source in the extension manager configuration page and see if that works better. Don't forget to clear all caches when testing new configuration.

Comment: 1. yes 2. yes  3. probably. what are the correct permissions ?

Comment: "chown www-data:www-data .htacces" and
"chmod 644 .htaccess"
This should do it. (remove the ""s, comments won't let me separate commands) This is ubuntu specific i think though, check what usergroup you use for apache, assuming you're using linux & apache?

Comment: permissions set correctly,  basic.autoConfFormat = PHP source

Comment: quick and dirty workaround created a another folder inside the root with the same name will for now :P