# multiple clients under single domain typo3

Tags: typo3, realurl

im trying to configure realurl to work with multiple clients but under a single domain and a single page tree

[root]

- client 1

  - page1
  - page2
- client 2

  - page 1
  - page 2

all clients have 'is Root page ' checked
they a have a template which is rootlevel

if they were different domains or at least subdomains then i would just create a Domain record in each of the root pages and forget about it but i cant instead i got this structure

`domain.com/client1/page1`

currently realurl is configured to automatically

im basically looking for a way to identify the clients

im getting this error when trying to access a client `domain.com/client1/`

> The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: Segment "client1"
>   was not a keyword for a postVarSet as expected on page with id=84.

id=84 is a root page with a Domain record that matches the domain in the url

**update 1**
i changed my structure to

[root]

- generic client

  - client 1

    - page1
    - page2
  - client 2

    - page1
    - page2

and removed 'Use as root page' along with the Domain Records from the clients

sometimes i over-complicate things for no reason :P

Comment: Have you tried to set the [absRefPrefix](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html) to `/client1/`, `/client2/` etc. per client and then if necessary remove the root-pages from the speaking URL path?

Comment: yes i have and it didnt look good :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706949/typo3-extension-real-url-returns-404-on-all-pages?rq=1

Comment: Ok. Another idea: Use domain records, and set the domain to `domain.com/client1/`. Found here: http://www.videc.at/2009/05/13/typo3-multi-domain-error-when-using-a-subdirectory-as-typo3-root-with-mod_alias/

Comment: that is my current configuration actually

Answer (score 0):

maybe you will find here your solution..
https://github.com/Ecodev/bootstrap_package/blob/master/htdocs/typo3conf/RealUrl.php

Comment: nope :( unless im missing something and you can point out something in specific